# Placing a div in a specific place above everything else so it doesn't move anything else?

Tags: html, css

Hoping someone can help.

My page is here:
http://www.simplypsychics.com/psychicprofile.php?pin=4439

Basically what I want to do is position an image in specific dimensions where RED is (in my picture below).

However, I tried to place it where the 'Psychic Name' is as an  with align="right" but it moves by tab content down.

Does anyone know how I can put it in, maybe as a DIV, so it's always above everything and in that very place as in my picture here:
http://i60.tinypic.com/2hmmvrl.jpg

I don't know what code I need to look at. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the "profileimg" that's currently overlapping the text.

Just use this css:

```
.profileimg {
    height: 118px;
    float: right;
}
```

No need to use absolute positioning, floating the image to the right gives you the effect you need.

Comment: That is second best to what I wanted! Looks okay. Thank you x

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the css of your "content" div (the div that contains the topic, the red picture, the form and so on ... but not the "other psychics content)

```
position: relative;
```

And add this to the div that contains your picture

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

If the position is not exactly what you wanted, you can change the position by change the values from `top` and `right`. If you do this, don't forget to add unit "px" (e.g. `top: 10px;`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it and it worked until I resized my browser and it moved along with it. Nevermind :(

Comment: Why is it wrong if the pictures reacts on the browser resize as long as it stays on it's position? Keep in mind the picture sticks to the upper right corner of it's parent div. If the div doesn't resize correctly the picture may show unwanted movements.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following CSS properties on `.profileimg`

```
.profileimg {
height: 118px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 18%;
}
```

I'm not saying that it's a great soloution but if you don't really know CSS then it's probably a quick fix until someone proper can look at it.

Comment: Hahaha I tried something like this and it just ignored my margin and moved everything down lol :@@@@@ thanks for answer x